# Excluding modules of a library using Google's Closure

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have a JavaScript library that includes several feature groups. Each group can be excluding from the compile without breaking the library (i.e. they are optional).

I've placed with feature in their own sub-module space.

```
gems.editors.*
gems.filters.*
gems.scaffold.*
etc.. etc..
```

I would like to make custom builds that exclude `gems.filters.*` for example.

Is there a way using the command line to set flags to tell Closure to exclude parts of the library by module?

Comment: If you use ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS, you can also get this working the other way around - only ask for the modules that are in use, and the rest will be cut away as dead code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set flags with the [@define](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler) annotation (optionally using goog.define()). I'm not sure if it works to wrap a goog.require() like

```
if (gems.ENABLE_EDITORS) {
  goog.require('gems.editors');
}
```

but you could definitely use the flag in the editors file itself:

```
goog.provide('gems.editors');

if (gems.ENABLE_EDITORS) {
  // editor code goes here
}
```

and then, when ENABLE_EDITORS is false, the compiler will remove all the unused code.